# Trying to set COM+ application component property in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, com+

I am  trying to check the **Run application as NT Service** box for an application in COM+ in Component Services using PowerShell.

Does anyone know the $component.Value(s) to do this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

In my case:

```
$comAdmin = New-Object -comobject COMAdmin.COMAdminCatalog
$comAdmin.ShutdownApplication("MqsAgent2")
$applications = $comAdmin.GetCollection("Applications") 
$applications.Populate() 

foreach ($application in $applications)
{
    if ($application.Name -eq "MqsAgent2")
    {
        $application.Value("Changeable") = $true   
    }
}

$applications.SaveChanges() | Out-Null

$comAdmin.StartApplication("MqsAgent2")

**$comAdmin.CreateServiceForApplication("MqsAgent2","MqsAgent2","SERVICE_AUTO_START","SERVICE_ERROR_CRITICAL","",".\MqsAgentUser","P@ssw0rd",$False)**

$comAdmin.ShutdownApplication("MqsAgent2")
$applications = $comAdmin.GetCollection("Applications") 
$applications.Populate() 

foreach ($application in $applications)
{
    if ($application.Name -eq "MqsAgent2")
    {
        $application.Value("Activation") = "1"
        $application.Value("Identity") = ".\MqsAgentUser"
        $application.Value("Password") = "P@ssw0rd"
    }
}

$applications.SaveChanges() | Out-Null
```

Hope it helps)